# Bring graphics to front F#

Tags: winforms, f#

I'm doing a project in which you should be able to create shapes in a windows forms environment. I've got two different shapes at the moment, called Circle1 and Rectangle1, they are just what they are called an have similiar properties.

```
type Rectangle1(x:int, y:int,brush1)=
  let mutable thisx = x
  let mutable thisy = y
  let mutable thiswidth = 50
  let mutable thisheight = 20
  let mutable brush = brush1
  member obj.x with get () = thisx and set x = thisx <- x
  member oby.y with get () = thisy and set y = thisy <- y
  member obj.brush1 with get () = brush and set brush1 = brush <- brush1
  member obj.width with get () = thiswidth and set width = thiswidth <- width
  member obj.height with get () = thisheight and set height = thisheight <- height
  member obj.draw(g:Graphics) = g.FillRectangle(brush,thisx,thisy,thiswidth,thisheight)
```

This rectangle is clickable and moveable, but I've encountered a problem. I need some kind of method that is similar to the c# bringToFront() method. So that when I click a shape, my shape goes to the front of all other shapes.

My storage list looks like this:

```
let mutable RectangleList:List<Rectangle1> =  []
```

And i use a hittest to determine whether the user hit a shape or not:

```
let rec VilketObjRec (e:MouseEventArgs) (inputlist:List<Rectangle1>) = 
match inputlist with
     |[] -> None
     |head::tail -> if (((e.X >= head.x) && (e.X <= (head.x + head.width))) && (e.Y >= head.y) && (e.Y <= (head.y+head.height))) 
                       then Some(head) else VilketObjRec e tail
```

Anyone got any kind of idea how to tackle this problem? Cause frankly, I'm lost.

Answer (score 3):

Based on the hit test function, it seems that your `RectangleList` stores the rectangles in a reversed order than the order in which they appear on the screen (the rectangle at the start is hit tested first and so it will be the one on the top of the drawing).

In that case, if you want to bring a rectangle to the top, you just need to move it to the beginning of the list. You can create a new list with the specified value at the beginning and then remove the value from the rest of the list using `filter`:

```
let BringToFront value list = 
  value :: (List.filter (fun v -> v <> value) list)
```

The function works on anly list, so here is an example using integers:

```
BringToFront 3 [ 1;2;3;4 ] = [3;1;2;4]
```

Answer (score 2):

Wmeyer's and Tomas's answers are nicely meet to your request for relatively small set of rectangles. In case you will use 10^3 and more rectangles and you know their coordinates before your GUI is started, there is simple static structure [enter link description here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segment_tree). In more complex case, 3rd chapter of "The Design And Analysis Of Spatial Data Structures" by Hanan Samet is your best friend.

Answer (score 1):

The basic idea: You could add a `z` coordinate to the `Rectangle1` class. When a rectangle is hit, make sure it gets the highest `z` value. Before drawing the rectangles, make sure they are sorted by ascending `z` value.